# What is this syntax used in Facebook's dispatcher.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

```
class Dispatcher<TPayload> {
  _callbacks: {[key: DispatchToken]: (payload: TPayload) => void}
  ...
```

It looks like TypeScript, but I'm able to compile it using Babel without TypeScript. I couldn't find anything about this in ES6 or ES7. What is this syntax called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [flow](http://flowtype.org/) annotations, it's Facebook's own type checker.